# Every guard in Skyrim is after me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can't get Skyrim guards to stop attacking me. I'm doing the Thieves Guild quest line and I'm just going into Markarth for the FIRST TIME, and the guards attack me immediately. All other guards in other cities (Whiterun, Riften, Winterhold) attack me too. I tried doing the thing where you sheath your wapons over and over, I've tried waitng 3 days, taking off my Thieves Guild armor, letting Uthgerd the Unbroken go, I don't know what to do next.

Added note, I haven't done a lot of the main quest so I technically don't even know I'm Dragonborn yet.

Comment: did you do something wrong and get a bounty??

Comment: They only attack you when you have a really high bounty... What did you do!? :D